# Using transactions in Django

Tags: python, django, atomic

I'm using django 1.11 on python 3.7

In a method I want to execute some database queries, mainly updating links between objects and I want to use this method to perform a check on what needs to be updated in a sync-operation. The following is an implementation:

```
    results = {}

    with transaction.atomic():
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        for speaker_user in speaker_users:
            # here my code checks all sorts of things, updates the database with
            # new connections between objects and stores them all in the
            # results-dict, using a lot of code in other classes which
            # I really dont want to change for this operation

        if sync_test_only:
            transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        else:
            transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)

    return results
```

This snippet is used in a method with the `sync_test_only` parameter that should only fill the results-dict without doing the database changes that go along with it.

So this method can be used to do the actual work, when `sync_test_only` is `False`, and also only report back the work to-be-done, when `sync_test_only` is `True`

Is this what the `transaction.atomic()` is designed for? Does this actually work in my use-case? If not, what would be a better way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried it to know if it works?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use exceptions, like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) suggest (read the part under the title "You may need to manually revert model state when rolling back a transaction"):

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def f(do_commit=False):
    results = {}

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            for speaker_user in speaker_users:
                pass

            if not do_commit:
                raise MyException
    except MyException:
        # do nothing here
        pass

    return results
```

I suggest creating a custom exception so you don't accidently catch something that was raised somewhere else in the code.

Comment: brillant bru ...